# How to check that table has field in json column?

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

how to check that table has column with index? What it is mean. I have a column with JSON type, and I have to check it, exist or not. I can use `Schema::connection()->hasColumn('table','column')` but in this method I can check only column and I can't type  `Schema::connection()->hasColumn('table','column->index->index1')` because it return - false all the time so I need in solution which will not check only column but also column in json

Comment: a json field can have any structure, it isn't defined on the field level ... so checking the schema won't help as the data isn't part of the schema

Comment: @lagbox ok, thank you. May be you know some method which does that. It does not matter how, result is more important. Because I really do not know, how to do that

Comment: there isn't because it isn't schema ... the json field in every row can have any structure it wants, its data in a field, not schema